# CosmosDB - How to query collection with multiple values

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following collection and I want to query based on `Class` and `FullName` from Students.

```
{
    "id" : "ABCD",
    "Class" : "Math",
    "Students" : [
        {
            "FullName" : "Dan Smith",
        },
        {
            "FullName" : "Dave Jackson",
        },
    ]
}
```

The following filter works based on class.

```cs
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Class, "Math");
var document = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But I want to query based on student also, I tried to add another filter and it has the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool

```cs
filter &= builder.Eq(x => x.Students.Any(y => y.FullName,"Dan"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to query with the nested document in an array, you need `$elemMatch` operator. In MongoDB .NET Driver syntax, you can achieve with either of these ways:

**Solution 1: ElemMatch with LINQ Expression**

```cs
filter &= builder.ElemMatch(x => x.Students, y => y.FullName == "Dan");
```

**Solution 2: ElemMatch with FilterDefinition**

```cs
filter &= builder.ElemMatch(x => x.Students, 
    Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(y => y.FullName, "Dan"));
```

The above methods will return no document as the filter criteria don't match with the attached document.

If you look for matching the partial word, you need to work with `$regex` operator.

**Solution: With regex match**

```cs
filter &= builder.ElemMatch(x => x.Students, 
    Builders<Student>.Filter.Regex(y => y.FullName, "Dan"));
```

> Demo

[image]